# Spring Boot - Use multiple JpaRepository interfaces in 1 application with a different package location

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, entitymanager

I have the following structure (packagecore is created to be refactored as a maven dependency so that we can also include it in packagerest for another app instead of duplicating all JPA entity, repository, etc). I need to have multiple `@Entity` objects accessible from the same DataSource / EntityManager, across different `JpaRepository` interfaces that are consumed from another package.

This is my project structure and what I've tried to achieve this without success:

```
com.packagebatch
  config
    BatchConfiguration
  App
com.packagecore
  database
    dto
      BatchFilesCompositeKey
      BatchFilesEntity
      BatchFilesHistEntity
      RequestEntity
    repository
      impl
        BatchFilesRepositoryImpl
        BatchFilesHistRepositoryImpl
        RequestRepositoryImpl
      BatchFilesRepository
      BatchFilesHistRepository
      RequestRepository
```

Each class in the dto package is annotated with `@Data @Entity @Table(...)` annotations.

Every interface in repository package looks as follows:

```
public interface BatchFilesRepository extends JpaRepository<BatchFilesEntity, BatchFilesCompositeKey> {...}

public interface BatchFilesHistRepository extends JpaRepository<BatchFilesHistEntity, Long> {...}

public interface RequestRepository extends JpaRepository<RequestEntity, Long> {...}
```

I tried tons of stuff with the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation to use all 3 repos in the `com.packagecore` package inside of the `com.packagebatch` package.

If I use 1, it is fine, but when a class uses both, I was getting errors like:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'batchFilesHistRepository' defined in class path resource [com/packagecore/database/repository/configuration/RepositoryConfiguration.class]: @Bean definition illegally overridden by existing bean definition: Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null
```

So, I refactored even more, I eventually added the impl subpackage and the following impls:

```
@Component("batchFilesHistRepositoryImpl")
public class BatchFilesHistRepositoryImpl extends SimpleJpaRepository<BatchFilesHistEntity, Long> implements BatchFilesHistRepository {
    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    public BatchFilesHistRepositoryImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(BatchFilesHistEntity.class, entityManager);
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    ...
```

Etc.

Now for BatchConfiguration, I have the following:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.packagecore", "com.packagebatch"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.packagecore", "com.packagebatch"} )
//@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.packagecore", "com.packagebatch"} )
public class BatchConfiguration {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchConfiguration.class);
    
    ...
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("batchFilesRepositoryImpl")
    private BatchFilesRepository batchFilesRepository;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("requestRepositoryImpl")
    private RequestRepository requestRepository;
```

When wiring up the app now, I get the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'requestRepository' defined in null: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] for bean 'requestRepository': There is already [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] bound.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:927)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn (RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:173)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.registerBeanDefinitions (RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.java:107)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$1 (ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:385)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach (LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars (ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass (ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:148)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions (ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions (ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry (ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors (PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors (PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors (AbstractApplicationContext.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:315)
```

I have done all I can to avoid overlapping JpaRepositoryFactoryBeans. By creating the interface impls, my understanding is my beans should wire as the impls I made, preventing them from conflicting with each other.

At this point, I am at a loss. I've spent 3+ days going back and forth with different suggestions and solutions on Stack Overflow. I didn't want to make any impls, because my interfaces used different stubbed out lookup methods with @Query annotations that preventing me from having to write that code, but I moved those queries into the entity as @NamedQuery annotations, and wrote the impl to use the EntityManager and call the named queries. Now, that that work is done, I was expecting the app to work, but I still have this same issue.

How I can wire up 2+ repo impls in 1 @Configuration, @Controller, @Service, etc. without getting this error? Where they are inside of a different package from the class they are used in. I've tried having all the interfaces tagged as @Repository("repositoryInterfaceClassName") and no tags on the impls, so spring would look for them; that didn't work. I tried using those tags on the impls, that didn't work. Then I tried changing those to @Component tags, then changing the names to specify the impl so that I can match those in my app. I tried using `@Resource("name")` and `@Autowired @Qualifier("name")`. I just can't seem to figure this out.

How can I make this work?

Comment: if you are going to implement repository iface on your own you need to place `@NoRepositoryBean` annotation over iface.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov, I found that and put that in an answer, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73013896/2658627

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the solution to my issue.

For all `database.repository` interfaces, I set them up with only a `@NoBeanRepository`, the impl classes all have no annotations on them.

Then I added the following class under `database.config` package:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.packagecore.database.repository"
)
public class RepositoryConfiguration {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    
    @Bean("batchFilesRepositoryImpl")
    public BatchFilesRepository getBatchFilesRepository() {
        return new BatchFilesRepositoryImpl(entityManager);
    }

    @Bean("batchFilesHistRepositoryImpl")
    public BatchFilesHistRepository getBatchFilesHistRepository() {
        return new BatchFilesHistRepositoryImpl(entityManager);
    }

    @Bean("requestRepositoryImpl")
    public RequestRepository getRequestRepository() {
        return new RequestRepositoryImpl(entityManager);
    }
}
```

For my main application under `com.packagebatch` app, I have it annotated with:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.packagecore", "com.packagebatch"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.packagecore", "com.packagebatch"})
@Import(RepositoryConfiguration.class)
@EnableBatchProcessing
```

The classes that use it are either annotated with only `@Component`, `@Configuration`, or `@Service`; as they are needed.

Then the `@Bean` from the configuration class is wired into them with an `@Autowired @Qualifier(...)` annotation.

At first, it looked like the app was hanging when I changed this up, but then, I realized my git log4j2.xml file doesn't dump out debug on the console log, so I took a look at the log dir and was able to find all my application logs look good now with this change.

Hopefully this info can help other people who are struggling.

Thanks!